# PyQt5 - arrancar programa

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo dos script separados, por una parte tengo el programa creado en python3 que se llama **conteo.py** y por otra parte tengo creada la GUI en PyQt5 llamada **interfaz.py** con las funcionalidades que necesito.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en el momento en que yo haga click en el boton "Inicio" de la interfaz, conecte con **conteo.py** e inicie el programa creado?

```
 self.btnInicio.clicked.connect(???)
```

¿Algún tipo de función que llame a la otra clase?

Archivo PyQt5 **interfaz.py**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(582, 484)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.btnIniciar.clicked.connect(self.launchScript)

    def launchScript(self):
        import proyectoFINAL 
        proyectoFINAL.mainFunction()
```

Archivo python3 **contador.py**

```
    def mainFunction():

        while(cap.isOpened()):

        grabbed, frame = redimensiona_frame()
        if grabbed == True:
            out.write(frame)
            text = "Carretera sin vehiculos"
        elif grabbed == False:
            print("Video finalizado")
            break
```

Archivo python3 **funciones.py**

```
with open ('C:/PROYECTO FINAL/configuracion.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as a_file:
    rutaVideo = a_file.readline().strip()
    param = a_file.readline().strip()
    param2 = a_file.readline().strip()
    param3 = a_file.readline().strip()   



cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rutaVideo)
```

Aqui os dejo algo de código de como más o menos está estructurado el programa.
Básicamente quiero pulsar el botón "inicio" y que se me abra el vídeo que he cargado el cual están ejecutando el algoritmo en la clase **conteo.py** y esta a su vez está llamando a la 3º clase **funciones.py** que es desde donde va a mandar el video.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: trata de siempre agregar un [mcve]

Comment: @RuslanLópez aquí dejo algo mas claro quizá lo que quiero. Muchas gracias por responder y por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Con lo que se ve a continuación soy capáz de iniciar el programa desde el IDE, pero cuando creo el interfaz a funcionar como .exe no me carga ningún video no hace nada.

Comment: Excelente, la nomino para reapertura, tal vez alguien que haya usado interfaces te pueda ayudar